# Php include path help for Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, include-path

I previously posted this question ([Reading Google docs spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515912/reading-google-docs-spreadsheet)) and got a good answer that instructed me to use the Zend Framework. I've never used it before, and I'm fairly certain I'm setting it up wrong. It says to "Simply download the framework,
extract it to the folder you would like to keep it in, and add the library directory
to your PHP include_path."

I'm doing it like this:

```
<?php
ini_set("include_path", ".:/PortableApps/xampp/htdocs/zend/library");
?>
```

...which is probably most certaintly wrong. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696152/how-to-change-include-directory-of-zend-framework) question. It will answer yours.